# How to keep window scroll position after screen rotation?

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, css

I have the problem to keep latest window scroll position after screen orientation has been changed.

For example, on the page

http://www.svoboda.mobi/a/27582777.html

when I scroll to the middle of the screen and then rotate from portrait to landscape or vice versa, the screen position is going to top of the page instead of to keep latest position.

It affects Android phones, iOS, and probably other devices. It's working correctly on Nokia Lumia 520.

I know, that I can use some javascript like

```
$(window).on(scroll, function() {

  //save the current scroll position somehow

});

$(window).on("orientationchange", function(event){

   //scroll window to saved position

});
```

but I don't want to solve that by this way. I still don't know, what is the cause of that? I think it must be some error in CSS, because when I turn off javascript, the problem still occurs. Thank you for help.